# python: how to change the name of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

My dict is a dict of `{str: {str: list of str}}`
ex:

```
{'hii':{'bye': [1, 2]}}
```

what i want:

```
{'hi':{'bye': [1, 2]}}
```

Is there a way to change the `'hii'` to just `'hi'`?

what I've tried only edits the values and not the keys.

Comment: There's no way to change keys as such.  You'll need to add a new key with the same value, then delete the old key.

Comment: **See also**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720673/renaming-the-keys-of-a-dictionary

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do need to remove and re-add, but you can do it one go with `pop`:

```
d['hi'] = d.pop('hii')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the old key/value pair and insert a new one:

```
d = {'hii': {'bye': [1, 2]}}
d['hi'] = d['hii']
del d['hii']
```

Comment: `d.pop` is another option

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a key in a dictionary, because the key object must be hashable, and therefore *immutable*. Daniel Roseman's answer looks like the most elegant way of accomplishing your goal.