# Renaming the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to change a key in a Python dictionary?

A routine returns a dictionary.
Everything is OK with the dictionary except a couple keys need to be renamed.  This code below copies the dictionary entry (key=value) into a new entry with the desired key and then deletes the old entry.  Is there a more Pythonic way, perhaps without duplicating the value?

```
my_dict = some_library.some_method(scan)
my_dict['qVec'] = my_dict['Q']
my_dict['rVec'] = my_dict['R']
del my_dict['Q'], my_dict['R']
return my_dict
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`dict` keys are immutable. That means that they cannot be changed. You can read more from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any ***immutable type***

Here is a workaround using [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.pop#dict.pop)

```
>>> d = {1:'a',2:'b'}
>>> d[3] = d.pop(1)
>>> d
{2: 'b', 3: 'a'}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if the key doesn't exit. Workaround would be d[new_key] = d.pop(old_new, default_value) eg: d[3] = d.pop(0, -1) if 0 is not in d.keys() it will assign -1 instead of throwing an error.